# Sum integers from a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I have a

```
table = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]
```

Using recursion and the `isinstance` function I need to sum all integers in `table`.
I can do it creating new list, extending it by lists from table. Then I got a normal list (no list in lists) and I can sum it.

But in this example I have no idea how to do it in a recursive way using that function. I understand how `isinstance` works, but I have no idea how to use it in this example.

In code below I don't even get different value than True.

```
tab = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]
for i in range(len(tab)):
    print(isinstance(i, int))
```

Excepted output is sum of all numbers

Comment: `for i in range(len(tab))` iterates all the indices in the top-level list, not their values. So it's normal that they're all `int`s.

Comment: Try `isinstance(tab[i], int)`, or just do `for i in tab:`.

Comment: what is your expected output? sum all number that are confirmed as integers?

Comment: Also, if you want to use recursion to solve this, you'll need to define a function (so that it can call itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion means you have to use a function.

```
tab = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]

def int_sum(tbl):
    s = 0
    for e in tbl:
        if isinstance(e, int):
            s += e
        else:
            # this is the trick!
            s += int_sum(e)
    return s

print(int_sum(tab))
```

Comment: Ouh, that simplest that I think and easy to understand. Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sum` with recursion:

```
table = [7, 5, [3, 6, [2]], 7, [1, [2, 3, [4]], 9, 2], 4]
def get_sum(d):
  return sum(i if isinstance(i, int) else get_sum(i) for i in d)

print(get_sum(table))
```

Output:

```
55
```